# Rcpp reports an error: C symbol name "sourceCppContext" not in DLL for package "Rcpp"

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying Rcpp 0.10.0 on Mac OS 10.8.2, and use the example [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2012/11/20/#rcpp_attributes_pi_example) about estimating \pi. However, when I run the following code in R:

`sourceCpp("piSugar.cpp")`

an error message says:

`Error in .Call("sourceCppContext", PACKAGE = "Rcpp", file, code, .Platform) : 
  C symbol name "sourceCppContext" not in DLL for package "Rcpp"`

Did I miss something? I double checked that the piSuger.cpp file is in current directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are calling an older Rcpp version. Maybe you have several in your `.libPaths()`?  Or maybe you didn't restart your session?

It all works here -- and `piBySimulation.r` is the example from my [blog post from an hour or two ago](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2012/11/20#rcpp_attributes_pi_example) which you are trying to replicate here:

```
edd@max:~/svn/rcpp/pkg/Rcpp/inst/examples/Misc$ Rscript piBySimulation.r
        test replications elapsed relative
2 piSugar(N)          100   5.639    1.000
1     piR(N)          100  11.147    1.977
edd@max:~/svn/rcpp/pkg/Rcpp/inst/examples/Misc$
```

Comment: Yes, I restart my R session and now it works. Thanks for the prompt reply :)